# Multiple items dropdown -output formatting

Tags: vba, excel

Could someone please help me with the below VBA code. Instead of displaying the results in different rows of the same cell, I want to display in different rows of the same column.

Your help would be very much appreciated!!!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
**' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel and display the 
' result in different rows for further calculations.** 
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
  If Target.Column = 8 Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            ***Target.Value = Oldvalue & Chr(10) & Newvalue***
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want people look at your code, please fix indent, to make life easier, after you fix the indent, highlight those you want to show, indent one more then copy paste here. Then manually add 4 spaces to Labels. This is no **vb.net** either.

Comment: PatricK I hope this would be better navigating now..sorry for the poor format before

Comment: Please highlight your code, press [Tab] once (twice if your setting is 2 spaces for Tab). Ctrl-C and then paste into Edit post. Code in image does not help. You have confusing If-Else blocks. What's the goal of the code?

Answer (score 0):

This sub passes the old value a cell below the range that triggered the sub. And passes the new value 2 cells below that same range.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Oldvalue As String  '<~ declare old value
Dim Newvalue As String  '<~ declare new value

Application.EnableEvents = True '<~enable events( idunno why)

  On Error GoTo ExitSub '<~ simple error handler
  If Not Target.Column = 8 Then GoTo ExitSub    '<~ if the change not happened in col8 then exit
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then GoTo ExitSub
  If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo ExitSub        '<~ if the new value is blank then exit

    Application.EnableEvents = False            '<~ disableevents
    Newvalue = Target.Value                     '<~ pass new value into a variable
    Application.Undo                            '<~ force undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value                     '<~ pass previous value into a variable
    Target.Value = Newvalue                     '<~ give new value
      If Not Oldvalue = "" Then                 '<~ check if old value is blank
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then '<~ check if the old value
            Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Old Value: " & Oldvalue    '<~ pass old value to a cell below the
            Target.Offset(2, 0).Value = "New Value: " & Newvalue    '<~ range that made a  change
        End If
      End If

ExitSub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```